# How to check if user is authenticated with Google or with Email and password?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'd like to implement a "Reset password" button in the settings of my app but I think I should enable it only for users authenticated with Email and password, and not for users logged with Google.

How could I check the authentication method? Because I could put an If statement and show the button only if the user is logged with email and password I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use,

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.providerData
```

To get the specific provider of the user's authentication.
Read more [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/manage-users#get-a-users-provider-specific-profile-information)

Answer (score 0):

Either store it in database how the given user logged in or you can use https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences to store a value.

```
enum LoginType {
  EMAIL, GOOGLE
}

main() {
   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

   if (userLoggedInWithEmail()) {
      await prefs.setString('USER_LOGGED_IN_WITH', LoginType.EMAIL.toString());
   } else {
      await prefs.setString('USER_LOGGED_IN_WITH', LoginType.GOOGLE.toString());
   }
}
```